# setting SQLite DataBase to TextView With ActionBar and AlertDialog

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, android-menu

[image]

Here having detail (firstname, lastname, mobile, password, email id) that is stored in database.

I set a list so that it will get my database details to `TextView`. I have done `DataBase`, `ActionBar`, `AlertDialogue`. while clicking `ActionBar` an `AlertDialog` will open. There by clicking "ok" button the details must arrange in `TextView`.

My code is given below:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String dataBaseName = "Login.db";

private static final int dataBaseVersion = 1;

private static final String tableName = "Accounts";
private static String Key_Id = "id";
private static String Key_FirstName = "firstname";
private static String Key_LastName = "lastname";
private static String Key_Password = "password";
private static String Key_Mobile = "mobile";
private static String Key_Email = "email";

public static String tag = "tag";

private static final String createTableAccounts = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "( " + Key_Id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Key_FirstName + " TEXT, " + Key_LastName + " TEXT, " + Key_Password + " TEXT, " + Key_Mobile + " TEXT, " + Key_Email + " TEXT );";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dataBaseName, null, dataBaseVersion);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(createTableAccounts);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + createTableAccounts);
    onCreate(db);

}

public long addAccountDetials(AccountsModel accounts) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Key_FirstName, accounts.firstName);
    values.put(Key_LastName, accounts.lastName);
    values.put(Key_Password, accounts.passWord);
    values.put(Key_Mobile, accounts.mobile);
    values.put(Key_Email, accounts.emailId);

    long insert = db.insert(tableName, null, values);
    return insert;
}

public int updateEntry(AccountsModel accounts) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Key_FirstName, accounts.firstName);
    values.put(Key_LastName, accounts.lastName);
    values.put(Key_Password, accounts.passWord);
    values.put(Key_Mobile, accounts.mobile);
    values.put(Key_Email, accounts.emailId);

    return db.update(tableName, values, Key_Id + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(accounts.id)});
}

public void deleteEntry(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(tableName, Key_Id + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}

public AccountsModel getAccounts(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE "
            + Key_Id + " = " + id;
    Log.d(tag, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    AccountsModel accountsModel = new AccountsModel();
    accountsModel.id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Id));
    accountsModel.firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_FirstName));
    accountsModel.lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_LastName));
    accountsModel.mobile = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Mobile));
    accountsModel.passWord = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Password));
    accountsModel.emailId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Email));

    return accountsModel;
}
public List<AccountsModel> getAllAccountList() {
    List<AccountsModel> accountsModelArrayList = new ArrayList<AccountsModel>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName;
    Log.d(tag, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            AccountsModel accountsModel = new AccountsModel();
            accountsModel.id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Id));
            accountsModel.firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_FirstName));
            accountsModel.lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_LastName));
            accountsModel.mobile = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Mobile));
            accountsModel.passWord = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Password));
            accountsModel.emailId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Key_Email));

            accountsModelArrayList.add(accountsModel);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return accountsModelArrayList;
}}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText firstName;
EditText lastName;
EditText mobile;
EditText password;
EditText email;

ListView listView;

List<AccountsModel>list=new ArrayList<AccountsModel>();

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseHelper =new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    firstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_firstname);
    lastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_lastname);
    mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_mobile);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_email);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_add) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("ADD DATA TO LIST");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,View v) {

                if(v == findViewById(R.id.action_add)){
                    listView.setAdapter(" ");
                    AccountsModel accountsModel = new AccountsModel();
                    accountsModel.firstName = firstName.getText().toString();
                    accountsModel.lastName = lastName.getText().toString();
                    accountsModel.mobile = mobile.getText().toString();
                    accountsModel.passWord = password.getText().toString();
                    accountsModel.emailId = email.getText().toString();

                    databaseHelper.addAccountDetials(accountsModel);
                    list = accountsModel.getAllAccountList();
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, value);

                String value = "";
                for (AccountsModel accountsModel : list) {
                    value = value + "id: " + accountsModel.id + ", firstName : " + accountsModel.firstName + " lastName : " + accountsModel.lastName + "mobile : " + accountsModel.mobile + " passWord : " + accountsModel.passWord + " email : " + accountsModel.emailId + "\n";
                }
                listView.setAdapter(value);
            }

        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

AccountsModel

```
public class AccountsModel {

public int id;
public String firstname;
public String lastname;
public String password;
public String mobile;
public String email;

public AccountsModel(int id,String firstname,String lastname,String password,String mobile,String email)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.firstname=firstname;
    this.lastname=lastname;
    this.password=password;
    this.mobile=mobile;
    this.email=email;
}
public  AccountsModel()
{

}}
```

Please modify code according to my app so that I can understand, as I am new to android.

error i am facing

> Error:(75, 45) error: cannot find symbol method getAllAccountList()
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: want to set my Database details to my listView adapter,so that can view my detials in ListView

Comment: What is the problem you are facing.

Comment: dont know how to set my detials to ListView

Comment: i list my error above code,they are the error i am facing

Comment: Someone please help!

Comment: I didnt get solution still; here i cant able to call "getallaccount" which in DatabaseHelper cant able to call to MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting `@Override` over 'onClick' method.

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          ...
   }
});
```

Comment: @override deleted;then?

Comment: Deleting @override ;shows error "Error:(64, 83) error: <anonymous com.example.rahul.actionbarwithlistview.MainActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(DialogInterface,int) in OnClickListener"

Comment: Did you delete all of them ?

Answer (score 0):

`accountsModel` is an object of the class `AccountsModel`. The class `AccountsModel` has no method called `getAllAccountList()`. This is the reason for the given error. The `getAllAccountList()` method is present in the class `DatabaseHelper` instead. So it should be referred to as `databaseHelper.getAllAccountList()` instead of `accountsModel.getAllAccountList()`. It's a really basic error, and I guess you should try looking into the line that AndroidStudio mentions to better understand the error.